# Attaching a Hover Effect

Tags: jquery-plugins, hover

I'm using this tickertype jquery plugin:

http://www.hungry-media.com/code/jQuery/tickerType/

And I'm trying to attach a hover effect to a link, the website can be found here:

http://dougmolineux.com/json/

But it's simply not working, my hover code looks like this:

```
  $(".mylink").hover(
      function () {
        alert("test");
        console.log("is this working?");
        //$("#test").html($(this).attr("id"));
        //$(this).addClass("hover");
      },
      function () {
        //$(this).removeClass("hover");
      }
    );
```

And my link looks like this:

```
    "<a href="#" class="mylink" id="home">home</a>": "example glossary",<br />
```

When I hover over the link nothing happens, is something wrong with my code? I have the js inside A document.ready function. I think that it may have something to do with the inclusion of the tickerType plugin, but its possible something maybe wrong with me code :)

Any advice would help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the typewriter code serializes the HTML, therefore dropping any events attached to the elements.

[It works with the effect off](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zBJa8/).

You can use the `live()` method to bind your events and it works. This works because it doesn't directly attach events, just lets events bubble to `document` where thier origin is checked and if it matches the selector, the event is fired.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/86YSu/).

Comment: Don't why I didn't think of trying that :) it does work with the effect off so it must be doing something like you suggest, thanks. I will accept this answer when I can

Comment: @Pete No worries, I tested it for myself. I will see if I can come up with a workaround for you. :)